# Finding if a Number if Prime or not In C

Tags: c, primes

I was writing a C Program to find if a number is prime or not. Everytime I run it and enter a number, the value of the input changes. PLease point out the loopholes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{

    int x;
    int y;
    y=getchar();
    for(x=2;x<y;++x){
       if(y%x != 0 && y!=x)
            printf(" THE NUMBER %d is  A  PRIME \n", y);
        else
            printf(" \r THE NUMBER %d IS NOT A PRIME", y);
            break;
    }
}
```

I use the Code::Blocks IDE with GCC Compiler

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged your program?

Answer (score 5):

`getchar` returns the ASCII code of a single character. Consequently, your program picks up the ASCII code of the first character of the number you input and checks if it is prime.

Instead, you need to read an integer:

```
scanf("%d", &y);
```

The complete program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{

    int x;
    int y;
    scanf("%d", &y);
    for(x=2;x<y;++x){
       if(y%x != 0 && y!=x)
            printf(" THE NUMBER %d is  A  PRIME \n", y);
       else {
            printf(" \r THE NUMBER %d IS NOT A PRIME", y);
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

Note: You can stop when `x >= sqrt(y)`

Answer (score 5):

As the name implies, `getchar()` gets a single character from standard input. For example, if you enter <kbd>3</kbd>, the `y` gets the ASCII code of the character `'3'`, which is obviously not what you want.

Try `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &y);
```

Comment: Thanks...Another question..The program accepts input only once..Can I make it take input multiple times      ..This is my code.                                                                                                                                                                           "29
 THE NUMBER 29 is  A  PRIME

Process returned 29 (0x1D)   execution time : 1.219 s
Press any key to continue."

Comment: @MukulMehta Use a loop?

Comment: Using a loop makes the same number to repeat. I want to enter a different number every time the program finishes execution.

Comment: I modifiied it..This is working fine..    


#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>



int main()

{
        for(;;){
        int x;
        int y;
        scanf("%d", &y);

                for(x=2;x<y;++x){
                if(y%x != 0 && y!=x)
                printf(" THE NUMBER %d is  A  PRIME \n", y);
            else
                printf(" \r THE NUMBER % IS NOT A PRIME", y);
                break;
        }

}

}

Comment: @MukulMehta, please place code changes into the original question, not as comments.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are calling `getchar()` which is used to input a single character and this is what happens in your case:

- `getchar()` returns a character.
- Character is then converted into integer when you store it in variable of type `int`.
- Hence that integer contains the ASCII of input character i.e. `3` will be stored as `51` that is the reason input changes.

What you need to do is to input an integer instead of character. Try this:

```
scanf("%d", &y);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `getchar()` is from `stdio.h`. I think that you are confused with `getch()` whcih is from `conio.h`

Answer (score 1):

First answers are correct about input for y:

```
scanf("%d", &y);
```

Also, please note that you should loop until square root of x, and not more if your want to optimize your algorithm (I won't demonstrate here why, it's a mathematical property).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// ...

int x;
int x_max;
int y;

scanf("%d", &y);
x_max = (int)floor(sqrt(y));

for(x=2;x<=x_max;++x){

// ...
```